# How to disable DYNAMICBASE in msbuild vcxproj

Tags: c++, msbuild, linker, bitcoin, aslr

I would like to pass the linker option [`/DYNAMICBASE:no`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/dynamicbase?view=msvc-160) to the msvc linker via the vcxproj file which msbuild is using to compile the project.

If someone would like to replicate my failures I am using [this vcxproj file](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/build_msvc/bitcoind/bitcoind.vcxproj) to compile bitcoind using this command to build the project:
`msbuild bitcoind/bitcoind.vcxproj /p:Platform=x64 /p:Configuration=Release /t:build`
While the project builds successfully when run `dumpbin \headers` against the compiled exe I get output containing:

```
8160 DLL characteristics
  High Entropy Virtual Addresses
  Dynamic base
  NX compatible
  Terminal Server Aware
```

I have attempted to modify the vcxproj file according to ["Passing /highentropyva- to CSC compiler from MSBuild command-line or project file".](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27571303/74359) Note the changes below also include `HighEntropyVA` as I wanted to verify that it was just an issue with setting the dynamicbase.

```
  <PropertyGroup Label="Globals">
    <FileAlignment>
      <HighEntropyVA>False</HighEntropyVA>
    </FileAlignment>
    <Link>
      <DynamicBase>False</DynamicBase>
    </Link>
    <ProjectGuid>{D4513DDF-6013-44DC-ADCC-12EAF6D1F038}</ProjectGuid>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

I also attempted to get this working using an answer to ["How to pass linker options to msbuild via command line?".](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17677604/74359) Whereby I created the following prop file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <ItemDefinitionGroup>
    <Link>
       <DynamicBase>False</DynamicBase>
       <HighEntropyVA>False</HighEntropyVA>
    </Link>
  </ItemDefinitionGroup>
</Project>
```

and then added to the build using the command:
`msbuild bitcoind/bitcoind.vcxproj /p:Platform=x64 /p:Configuration=Release /t:build /p:ForceImportBeforeCppTargets=profile.props`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To turn off `/DYNAMICBASE` in the `.vcxproj` file insert the following before the `<ItemGroup>` list.

```
  <ItemDefinitionGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|x64'">
    <Link>
      <RandomizedBaseAddress>false</RandomizedBaseAddress>
    </Link>
  </ItemDefinitionGroup>
```

To have it apply to all builds, instead of just Release x64,  remove the `Condition=` part.

When `/DYNAMICBASE` is off, `/HIGHENTROPYVA` is ineffective, though the characteristic bit  may still be set in the header. To turn it off, add `<AdditionalOptions>/HIGHENTROPYVA:NO%(AdditionalOptions)</AdditionalOptions>` next to the `<RandomizedBaseAddress>` line.