# How to override all project properties for Visual Studio 2010 in msbuild through Powershell

Tags: visual-studio-2010, powershell, msbuild, build-script

I am trying to write a script where automatically build in 30+ Visual Studio 2010 (.sln) through PowerShell script using Msbuild command line.

I am able to build the build the modules, but I have some dependency and specific project setting for all 30+ modules. Project properties for all 30+ modules are same. So I want to pass all the project properties once in the script to set for all modules for building automatically.

But,

I am not able to pass all the project setting where as only 3 parameters I am able to pass such `/t:build /p:configuration:Debug /p:TargetPaltform=x86`.

Issue: I want to pass all project properties as arguments for `msbuild` in my `pwoershell` script.

Could you please provide some syntax or idea how can I pass more project properties parameters as command line?

Example Parameters List:

```
Output Directory
Intermediate Directory
Include Directories
Library Directories
Output File and sub sections. etc.
```

Comment: `/p:configuration:Debug` -> `/p:configuration=Debug`

Comment: use the principle laid out here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17446623/128384

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set PreProcessorDefinitions as a task propery for the msbuild task](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15141429/how-to-set-preprocessordefinitions-as-a-task-propery-for-the-msbuild-task)