# Override property sheet on the command line

Tags: msbuild

I am searching for a way to pass a property sheet (.props file) on the command line to MSBuild. MSBuild does not seem to have a specific switch for property sheets, but does have a `/property` [command line switch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164311.aspx), which you can use to override individual properties within the project.

Is there some way to either provide a property sheet on the command line, or, perhaps use the `/property` switch to apply the property sheet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your project file add an Import like

```
<Import Project="$(CustomProps)" Condition="Exists($(CustomProps))" />
```

Just add it where the other imports are, or if you don't want to repeat yourself for each configuration/platform combination, add it either below the `<Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.props"/>` line (in which case other property sheets can override values from it) or above the `<Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.targets"/>` line (so you can apply 'final' values with your custom property sheet).

Then on the commandline pass `/p:CustomProps=/path/to/props`

**edit** msbuild also has this functionality built-in, just figured this is sort of a duplicate of [How to set PreProcessorDefinitions as a task propery for the msbuild task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15141429/how-to-set-preprocessordefinitions-as-a-task-propery-for-the-msbuild-task/17446623#17446623). Except there if you want to control where the import happens you'd have to choose between ForceImportBeforeCppTargets and ForceImportAfterCppTargets.