# pass global options such as /Zm through msbuild (14.0)

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild

How can I pass the annoying `/Zm500` (500% virtual memory, because MS compiler is to stupid and even 32bit) through "msbuild.exe" such that when compiling a solution with it uses this option for every "cl.exe" invocation?

Comment: there is also a 64bit cl.exe

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set PreProcessorDefinitions as a task propery for the msbuild task](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15141429/how-to-set-preprocessordefinitions-as-a-task-propery-for-the-msbuild-task)

Answer (score 2):

> How can I pass the annoying /Zm500 through "msbuild.exe"

We could not pass the global option /Zm via the MSBuild command line directly. Because the `PreprocessorDefinitions` of `CLCompile`, which is **not** a `PropertyGroup`.

```
  <ClCompile>
    <AdditionalOptions>/bigobj  /Zm500 %(AdditionalOptions)</AdditionalOptions>
    <DisableSpecificWarnings>4453;28204</DisableSpecificWarnings>
  </ClCompile>
```

**As a workaround** for this question, you can add a target invoke MSBuild to pass an external parameter into the project file by MSBuild command line:

First, change the fixed values of “/Zm500” with $(Zm) in the project file:

```
  <ItemDefinitionGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'">
<ClCompile>
   <AdditionalOptions>/bigobj  $(Zm) %(AdditionalOptions)</AdditionalOptions>
   <DisableSpecificWarnings>4453;28204</DisableSpecificWarnings>
</ClCompile>
```

Second, add a target in to the project file:

```
<Target Name="TestBuild" Returns="@(ManagedTargetPath)">
    <MSBuild Projects="YourProjectName.xxproj" Targets="NormalBuild" Properties="Zm=/Zm500"/>
  </Target>
```

Third, use the MSBuild command line with the properties /Zm:

```
msbuild.exe "$(ProjectPath)\.xxproj" /p:Zm=/Zm500
```

Comment: You *can* do this without modifying the project using one of the extension points, see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15141429/how-to-set-preprocessordefinitions-as-a-task-propery-for-the-msbuild-task/17446623#17446623

Comment: @stijn, That looks like a very nice way, I will try it later, I have updated my answer, thanks for your sharing.