# override project properties on execting msbuild

Tags: cmake, msbuild, visual-studio-2005

I have a **Visual Studio 8 2005** project generated by cmake. Is there any way to override some properties (RuntimeLibrary, WarnAsError, WarningLevel) listed in *.vcproj project file at msbuild call in command line?

Unfortunately, this doesn't work:

```
msbuild my_project.sln /p:Configuration=Debug,WarnAsError=false,RuntimeLibrary=1
```

Comment: If it has to be "at msbuild call in command line", then this is not about CMake but about msbuild.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set PreProcessorDefinitions as a task propery for the msbuild task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15141429/how-to-set-preprocessordefinitions-as-a-task-propery-for-the-msbuild-task)

Answer (score 0):

In order to set multiple properties, you need to separate them using a semicolon (`;`), not commas (`,`). It is also possible to use multiple `/p:` arguments:

```
msbuild my_project.sln /p:Prop1=Value2;Prop2=Value2 /p:Prop3=Value3
```

Comment: good catch, but that won't help in setting compiler options which is likely the gist of the question