# Can I set a compiler option using MSBuild command line?

Tags: c++, msbuild

I want to, for example, enable showing includes (`\showIncludes` from C++ compiler Advanced configurations) for some project via MSbuild command line. Can I make it somehow without changing the project properties?

The following command line I tried doesn't work:

`MSBuild.exe /p:Configuration=Debug /p:Platform=x64 /p:ShowIncludes=true "myproj.vcxproj" -t:Rebuild`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set PreProcessorDefinitions as a task propery for the msbuild task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15141429/how-to-set-preprocessordefinitions-as-a-task-propery-for-the-msbuild-task) that question is for preprocessor definitions, but the principle for other compiler/linker/... options is the same

Comment: @stijin, so how can I use this information particularly for setting "showIncludes" flag? Did you try it or you thing that it should work in theory?

Comment: No I didn't try, but I know it works in practice because I've used it for all kinds of compiler flags. In this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/17446623/128384, all you have to do is replace the line `<PreprocessorDefinitions ....` with `<ShowIncludes>True</ShowIncludes>`. *edit* just tried, works.

Comment: Thanks, but (as I understand) you propose modifying a config file? A problem is to define that flag via a command line, without editing any files (if it ever possible)

Comment: It's been a while since I checked, but unless something changed in msbuild, it is not possible without using a file. Which is actually almost orthogonal to 'using commandline' because it's not too hard to create e.g. a Powershell commandline which creates the Directory.build.props file, calls msbuild, then deletes the config file again. And you can make this generic, e.g. if the file contains `<AdditionalOptions>$(ClOptions) %(AdditionalOptions)</AdditionalOptions>` then you can use `msbuild /p:ClOptions=/showIncludes` (and note you only need one such file, in the project root or even higher)

Answer (score -1):

Yes, [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/showincludes-list-include-files?view=vs-2019) are docs. You need to pass `/showIncludes`:

```
MSBuild.exe /p:Configuration=Debug /p:Platform=x64 /showIncludes "myproj.vcxproj" -t:Rebuild
```

[Example](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/YzQRdT)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But this didn't work for me. This is what I got after executing with the parameter:
MSBUILD: error MSB1001: Unknown key
Key: /showIncludes

Comment: your example with MSVC works but is not relevant to the question. Since I want to set the key via the MSBuild command line particularly, not with MSVC.