# Solution level preprocessor definitions in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-c++, msbuild

I have a large solution (100 projects) and a lot of them rely on a preprocessor definition (`NEWGUI`) in a header file (`shared.h`) to switch between two valid states of code (old gui and new gui).

I'm trying to add a compile guard around this macro

```cpp
#ifndef OLDGUI
#define NEWGUI
#endif
```

so that we don't have to comment out or delete that line in `shared.h` to build the old gui, which slows down incremental builds. Then, I'm hoping to find a way to set `OLDGUI` outside cf the configuration. With CMake we could do this with `cmake .. -DOLD_GUI`

I'm doing the building in an [MSBuild task in azure pipelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/msbuild?view=azure-devops).

My first attempt to get `OLDGUI` set on the solution was use the -p flag to set the preprocessor definition, but I realized that that overrides all existing preprocessor definitions.

My second attempt was to create a new configuration that just overrode the project that has the `shared.h` and add a preprocessor definition there, but that doesn't affect all the other projects that depend on `shared.h`, and the build ends up producing a chimera of old gui and new gui.

I'm not at all sure what the proper way to do this is, and I'm hoping I don't have to manually add configurations to 100 projects to add `OLDGUI` to each one individually. With MSBuild this looks increasingly cumbersome. So my question is: how can I do this? Initial thoughts:

1. Is there some way to use something like `-p:PreprocessorDefinitions=OLDGUI` to *add* to existing preprocessor definitions at compile time?
2. Is there some way to add a global property page to all the projects just under a single configuration so that I can define `OLDGUI` there?
3. Is there some way to add a global property page to all the projects at compile time to do the same thing as (2)?

Comment: I would like to know what details are requested? Because I have no idea what's missing from this post to make it intelligible.

Comment: Looks like a decent and understandable question to me. Don't have an answer for you, though.

Comment: This looks promising https://stackoverflow.com/a/14206134/9691276

Answer (score 0):

The solution was found in this answer from 2013. It's a hack, but it'll do.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/14206134/9691276

The approach I took was this:

Add `$(ExternalPreprocessorDefinitions)` to C++>Preprocessor in a global property page inherited by every project (this is pre-existing).

In the build pipeline, just set the environment variable `ExternalPreprocessorDefinitions=OLDGUI`.

Voila.